# Initialization by variables within normal brackets

Tags: c++, initialization

Today i got something like this:

```
const ciag geometryczny1 =  (rozmiar, iloraz1);
```

It solves a geometric sequence where `ciag` was for me to define (I decided it'd be a structure - I'm not allowed to use class yet), `rozmiar` is the size of the sequence and `iloraz1` is the multiplier.

All things aside I simply don't understand that initialization `type var_name = (value1, value2);`

How does it work ? Could anybody provide links to tutorials or explain it to me the easy way?

I'd appreciate that !

Comment: Are you sure it's not `{rozmiar, iloraz1}`?

Comment: It's the comma operator.

Comment: class = struct in C++. If you’re not allowed to use one, you’re not allowed to use the other.

Answer (score 0):

it's an issue of `comma operator'.

```
const ciag geometryczny1 =  (rozmiar, iloraz1);
```

equals to:

```
const ciag geometryczny1 = iloraz1;
```

when 'iloraz1' is of ciag compatible type, or ciag has constructors from type of `iloraz1', it should works.